# Вывести товары под каждой категорией woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Всем привет
У меня есть страница где выводится подкатегории мне нужно сделать так чтобы под каждой подкатегорией отображался свой товар. Все что у меня получалось это либо выводить все товары из всех категорий или выводить товары из определенной категории таким шорткодом [product_category category="samsung"] но его проблема в том что там нужно писать определеную категорию.
вот мой код подкатегорий

```html
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
?>

<li <?php wc_product_cat_class( '', $category ); ?>>
    <?php
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory', $category );

do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_subcategory_title', $category );

    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', $category );


    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory', $category );
    ?>
<?php
?>
  <div id="show__all">
    <?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_subcategory', $category );
echo "Показать все"; echo $category->count;
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', $category );
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory', $category );
        ?>
      </div>

<?php get_sidebar('product'); ?>

</li>
```

Comment: Задача не понятна. Нет упоминания где ты шаманишь (файл/шаблон), нет скрина, что бы видеть что имеешь и хочешь получить. Почему у тебя есть в шаблоне <li>, но нет <ul>? Где обёртки? Вопросов много и из твоего вопроса понять нет возможности.

Comment: Тебе надо не огород городить, что ты делаешь, а на хук (woocommerce_after_subcategory_title) вешать вывод товаров, но вопрос - нафига? Ты пишешь не пойми что (ИМХО). Смешал в файле шаблона content-product-cat.php огород и думаешь что будет работать? Нет, это так не работает.

Answer (score 0):

На этот счёт уже писалось вот тут - [Woocommere, как вывести товары под категорией на странице магазина?](https://qna.habr.com/q/407217)